# Having problems with my will_paginate after upgrading to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

The problem is that I keep getting

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `paginate' for #<Class:0x1e3dec0>):
activerecord (3.0.3) lib/active_record/base.rb:1008:in `method_missing'
```

Below is the code snippet I am including and any help in fixing my problem. I am using will_paginate-rails3 at the moment.

```
def list
   @users = User.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => 1
end
```

in `user_controller.rb`

and also

```
<!-<%= link_to 'Previous page', { :page => @users.previous_page } if @users.previous_page %>-->
```

in my `views.html`.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have the `will_paginate` gem listed in your Gemfile? And have you ran the `bundle` command?

Comment: also did you include the code in your model?

Comment: Also, not sure you need to use `will_paginate-rails3`. The wiki docs say `gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.pre2"` in your Gemfile will work.

Answer (score 2):

Did you use the Rails 3 branch of will_paginate? It's here:

https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/tree/rails3

Specify it in your Gemfile like this:

```
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.beta'
```

then install it like this:

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, worked like a charm, need to clean up the deprecations now.